# google compute engineのautoscalerを一時停止する方法

Tags: api, google-compute-engine

デプロイ中にサーバの数が増減すると困るのでgoogle compute engineのautoscalerを一時停止する方法を探しています。

AWSにはAutoScaleを中断(suspend_processes)したり,再開(resume_processes)したりするAPIが用意されているようなのですがgoogle compute engineにも同様のAPIは用意されているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

中断・再開自体は現状では無いと思われます。
増減すると困るというお話であれば、
Autoscaler APIのAutoscalers#patch()やAutoscalers#update()
で、MaxとMinを指定出来ますので、これを指定しておけばほぼ同様の動作になるかと思います。
同じマシーンが稼働し続ける保証は無いかもですが。。
デプロイ中とかくらいであれば、ほぼ問題無い、かと。

Comment: なるほど、MaxとMinをデプロイのタイミングのインスタンス数で固定するれば、欲しい機能の代用になりそうです。やってみます！